# Is -moz-inline-stack; not being supported by Firefox anymore?

Tags: css, firefox

Is that something wrong with `-moz-inline-stack;` ?

I've been using Cross Browser Inline-Block recently and had no issues with Firefox but now I am facing a display issue on that browser.

Once I removed `-moz-inline-stack;` and used `display: inline-block;` it worked fine.

Is Firefox not supporting `-moz-inline-stack;` anymore?

**This didn't work in Firefox:**

```
div {
        display: inline-block;
        display: -moz-inline-stack;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
```

**However this worked on Firefox:**

```
div {
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            zoom: 1;
        }
```

Comment: You should always put prefix-free version after the browser specific one, so your code won't break when browser stops supporting vendor-prefixed value.

Comment: There is no reference to `inline-stack` on the "Display" section at MDN. I think it's safe to say it's dead.

Comment: It's still listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions